# Joining the results of an SQL query with another one

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
SELECT BRAND.NAME, FIXTURE.NAME AS FIXTURE_NAME, FIXTURECATEGORY.NAME AS FIXTURE_CATEGORY
FROM            V_APPROVED_FIXTURES FIXTURE INNER JOIN
                         BRAND ON FIXTURE.BRAND_ID = BRAND.ID INNER JOIN
                         FIXTURECATEGORY ON FIXTURE.FIXTURECATEGORY_ID = FIXTURECATEGORY.ID INNER JOIN
                         FIXTURE_MODE ON FIXTURE.ID = FIXTURE_MODE.FIXTURE_ID AND FIXTURE.VERSION = FIXTURE_MODE.FIXTURE_VERSION RIGHT JOIN
                         FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER ON FIXTURE_MODE.ID = FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.FIXTURE_MODE_ID AND FIXTURE_MODE.FIXTURE_ID = FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.FIXTURE_ID AND 
                         FIXTURE_MODE.FIXTURE_VERSION = FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.FIXTURE_VERSION

GROUP BY BRAND.NAME, FIXTURE.NAME, FIXTURECATEGORY.NAME
HAVING        COUNT(FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.ORDINAL)=25
```

which produces a list of unique results and i want to combine it with this

```
SELECT BRAND.NAME, FIXTURE.NAME AS FIXTURE_NAME, FIXTURECATEGORY.NAME AS FIXTURE_CATEGORY
FROM            V_APPROVED_FIXTURES FIXTURE INNER JOIN
                         BRAND ON FIXTURE.BRAND_ID = BRAND.ID INNER JOIN
                         FIXTURECATEGORY ON FIXTURE.FIXTURECATEGORY_ID = FIXTURECATEGORY.ID INNER JOIN
                         FIXTURE_MODE ON FIXTURE.ID = FIXTURE_MODE.FIXTURE_ID AND FIXTURE.VERSION = FIXTURE_MODE.FIXTURE_VERSION RIGHT JOIN
                         FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER ON FIXTURE_MODE.ID = FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.FIXTURE_MODE_ID AND FIXTURE_MODE.FIXTURE_ID = FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.FIXTURE_ID AND 
                         FIXTURE_MODE.FIXTURE_VERSION = FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.FIXTURE_VERSION
GROUP BY BRAND.NAME, FIXTURE.NAME, FIXTURECATEGORY.NAME
HAVING        COUNT(FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.ORDINAL)=13
```

So, i want to see all the fixtures that have both 13 and 25 `COUNT(FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.ORDINAL)`

How can i do this?

Comment: If the number of columns and the names are the same you can use a UNION

Comment: Without having read all your post I believe you are looking for UNION clause

Comment: Just change your `HAVING` clause of one of those queries to be: `HAVING        COUNT(FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.ORDINAL)=25 OR COUNT(FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.ORDINAL)=13`. a UNION or an INTERSECT would be unnecessarily costly here. Or you could probably do `HAVING  COUNT(FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.ORDINAL) in (13, 25)` if it's allowed by your rdbms.

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is no need to write everything in UPPERCASE in SQL.

Comment: Unrelated, I had this one time when I wrote a SQL answer completely in lower case, and someone edited the answer to put it all in upper case. Naturally the edit got rejected since it didn't fix anything. But it just shows how some people like their SQL to shout. Not that it matters though, it's an esthetic choice.

Answer (score 2):

Since your two queries look identical except for the where condition. Just combine there where with an `or` or `in`

```
HAVING COUNT(FIXTURE_MODE_PARAMETER.ORDINAL) in(13,25)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a Union statement between that queries, like this:

```
Select * from tableA
Union
Select * from tableB
```

You will have to put your group by after the second table, like this:

```
Select * from tableA
Union
Select * from tableB
Group by [Column]
```

Comment: Mmmm... Are you sure for the group by ? I'd have said that each query has its own GROUP BY, HAVING and ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: When you union two statements together they essentially become one. Then you perform your group by and then your having, like this:

Select * from tableA
Union
Select * from tableB
Group by [Column]
Having blah blah blah

Comment: I'm sorry to said you're wrong : each of the two requests have its own group by, having, and probably even order by clause. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oyGWdy
If you want a clause to apply to the union you've got to do SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...) GROUP BY...